# error while updating arraylist to the mysql database to php

Tags: php, mysql, arraylist

i can send two array list android to php

```
                      [p,q,r,s,t,u](old menuname)
                      [a,b,c.d,e.f](new menunames)
```

i am having test table in that table contains one column menunames it updating properly. now i add another column as menuimage i can insert menuimages(blob) to the menuimage column in mysql database . now i want perform update menunames means it update only first row . remaining rows are not updated.

```
      i try this code
      <?php
    $old_menu_names=explode(',',preg_replace('/^.*\
    [(.*)\].*$/','$1',trim($_POST['menuname'], '[]'))); 

    $new_menu_names=explode(',',preg_replace('/^.*\
    [(.*)\].*$/','$1',trim($_POST['editmainmenu'], '[]'))); 

    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
    mysql_select_db("test"); 

    $i = 0;
    foreach ($old_menu_names as $key => $old_name)
    {
       $new_name = mysql_real_escape_string($new_menu_names[$i]);
       $old_name  = mysql_real_escape_string($old_menu_names[$key]);
       echo $new_name;
       mysql_query("UPDATE `test` SET `menuname` = '$new_name' WHERE menuname =   '$old_name'")
       or die('Error' . mysql_error());
       echo "Updated"; 
       $i++;
    }
```

?>

i can print response of this line is echo $new_name;  echo "Updated";  aUpdated bUpdated c\nUpdated dUpdated eUpdated fUpdated

but only first is updated remaining rows are not updated

Answer (score 0):

Umh...

Probably there is an error in your regular expressions..

Dump the $old_menu_names variable before the foreach.

```
print_r($old_menu_names);
```

Comment: it cannot print any thing please can u edit my code send to me